# Disable products is displayed in search result

Tags: magento, search, attributes

How can I set up to show only enable products in search result page?

Tried to disable attribute that the products belong to but it can't work well. 
Category set up issue? or other reason?

Could someone let me know the solution?

Comment: Please give more information. Language, framework, system, etc. Post actual examples of your code so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

please see this image
[image: Magento set visibility]

if you set the `visibility` to `catalogue, search`, then only enabled products will be shown..also, for disabled products, you might need to set the visibility to `NOT VISIBLE INDIVIUDALLY`

HTH

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried to change Visiblity but not working well.

Comment: Hello All,

I have also need suggestion and solution for this issue.

I have also face same issue.

I need specific code that might be solution of it.

Thanks,
Naitik

Comment: @NaitikMistry can you explain your requirement and statement a bit more please?

Comment: I have need only enabled products list displayed in search box but not displayed disabled products list.
Let me know if you have any doubt for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got that solution of stop disabled products list in Auto Complete Search box.

Please add the following code:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Autocomplete.php

Code add in public function getSuggestData()
{
    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $querynm = $item['query'];              
    $selq = $connection->query( "SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE value ='$querynm'");
    $setcqty = $selq->fetch();
    $eid = $setcqty['entity_id'];

    $selqe = $connection->query( "SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_int WHERE entity_id ='$eid' AND attribute_id='273'");
    $setcqtye = $selqe->fetch();
    $eid_st = $setcqtye['value'];

    if($eid_st == 1) {
    }
}
```

Try this Code. You will get only enabled products list in Search box.

Regards,
N@itik